# Kotlin - Google Maps Direction by Static Url

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, google-maps, maps

So, I have a Static Google Map, like the following:

[Static Google Map Link](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Madrid&zoom=14&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap&key=key&markers=Madrid)

And I want it to, when I click on the image view, that contains that static map, to start Google Maps with that direction.

I've used Intent... but it always breaks & don't work.

Code:

```
binding.imgview.setOnClickListener {
       
        val uri = Uri.parse(https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Madrid&zoom=14&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap&key=YOUR_API_KEY&markers=Madrid)

        val googleMapsPackage = "com.google.android.apps.maps"
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri)

        intent.setPackage(googleMapsPackage)


        context?.startActivity(intent)
    }
```

Any quest, feel free to ask :)
Thanks.

Comment: I've removed the API key from the post for security and privacy concerns. Please don't share private API keys on public sites, and make sure you restrict them as per https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#restrict_apikey

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 val uri =Uri.parse("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Madrid&zoom=14&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap&key=YOUR_API_KEY&markers=Madrid")

            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri)
            intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity")
            startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: It just open the Google Maps, but it doesn't set the URL location.

Comment: I've removed the API key from the post for security and privacy concerns. Please don't share private API keys on public sites, and make sure you restrict them as per https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#restrict_apikey